# Can't add new bookmarks for Firefox 34.0.5 on Win7 x64

Tags: windows-7, firefox

In a heavily locked down environment, I use Firefox 34.0.5 on a Win7 x64 machine. I am unable to add bookmarks, either by {Ctrl-D} or by tab drag-and-drop to the Bookmarks Bar. They do not appear in the Unsorted Bookmarks, I checked.

There are no add-ons installed.

How might I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your IT department will have to help you, your network policies, are the problem

Comment: If You is who control lock down, try to run it from command line. Possibly You see some error messages. Or try run it under RegMon or FileMon to view whar filesystem and registry access errors happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the IT department delete my Firefox profile, which solved the problem, and said issue has not recurred in two weeks of use.

People having similar issues can follow the steps in this guide: [Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems).